# Provide credentials to pgadmin Docker container: the user does not have permission to read and write to the specified storage directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, permissions, pgadmin

I'd like to provide the db credentials to pgadmin at startup.
I have the following error (scroll to the bottom):

```
postgis        | 
postgis        | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgis        | 
postgis        | 2023-03-01 23:55:55.287 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
postgis        | 2023-03-01 23:55:55.288 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgis        | 2023-03-01 23:55:55.288 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgis        | 2023-03-01 23:55:55.296 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgis        | 2023-03-01 23:55:55.301 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2023-03-01 23:54:41 UTC
postgis        | 2023-03-01 23:55:55.603 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
postgis        | 2023-03-01 23:55:55.607 UTC [29] LOG:  redo starts at 0/402DCF0
postgis        | 2023-03-01 23:55:55.607 UTC [29] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/402DD28: wanted 24, got 0
postgis        | 2023-03-01 23:55:55.607 UTC [29] LOG:  redo done at 0/402DCF0 system usage: CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s
postgis        | 2023-03-01 23:55:55.612 UTC [27] LOG:  checkpoint starting: end-of-recovery immediate wait
postgis        | 2023-03-01 23:55:55.620 UTC [27] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.002 s, sync=0.002 s, total=0.011 s; sync files=2, longest=0.002 s, average=0.001 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB
postgis        | 2023-03-01 23:55:55.629 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
backend exited with code 0
pgadmin        | NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.
pgadmin        | 
pgadmin        | Traceback (most recent call last):
pgadmin        |   File "/pgadmin4/run_pgadmin.py", line 4, in <module>
pgadmin        |     from pgAdmin4 import app
pgadmin        |   File "/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py", line 93, in <module>
pgadmin        |     app = create_app()
pgadmin        |   File "/pgadmin4/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 487, in create_app
pgadmin        |     paths.init_app()
pgadmin        |   File "/pgadmin4/pgadmin/utils/paths.py", line 102, in init_app
pgadmin        |     raise InternalServerError(
pgadmin        | werkzeug.exceptions.InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error: The user does not have permission to read and write to the specified storage directory.
pgadmin        | ----------
pgadmin        | Loading servers with:
pgadmin        | User: pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
pgadmin        | SQLite pgAdmin config: /var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4.db
pgadmin        | ----------
pgadmin        | Added 0 Server Group(s) and 1 Server(s).
pgadmin        | [2023-03-01 23:56:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
pgadmin        | [2023-03-01 23:56:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:80 (1)
pgadmin        | [2023-03-01 23:56:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
pgadmin        | [2023-03-01 23:56:21 +0000] [93] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 93
pgadmin        | [2023-03-01 23:56:25 +0000] [93] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
pgadmin        | Traceback (most recent call last):
pgadmin        |   File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
pgadmin        |     worker.init_process()
pgadmin        |   File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 92, in init_process
pgadmin        |     super().init_process()
pgadmin        |   File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
pgadmin        |     self.load_wsgi()
pgadmin        |   File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
pgadmin        |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
pgadmin        |   File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
pgadmin        |     self.callable = self.load()
pgadmin        |   File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
pgadmin        |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
pgadmin        |   File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
pgadmin        |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
pgadmin        |   File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
pgadmin        |     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
pgadmin        |   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
pgadmin        |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
pgadmin        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
pgadmin        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
pgadmin        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
pgadmin        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
pgadmin        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
pgadmin        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
pgadmin        |   File "/pgadmin4/run_pgadmin.py", line 4, in <module>
pgadmin        |     from pgAdmin4 import app
pgadmin        |   File "/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py", line 93, in <module>
pgadmin        |     app = create_app()
pgadmin        |   File "/pgadmin4/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 487, in create_app
pgadmin        |     paths.init_app()
pgadmin        |   File "/pgadmin4/pgadmin/utils/paths.py", line 102, in init_app
pgadmin        |     raise InternalServerError(
pgadmin        | werkzeug.exceptions.InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error: The user does not have permission to read and write to the specified storage directory.
pgadmin        | [2023-03-01 23:56:25 +0000] [93] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 93)
pgadmin        | [2023-03-01 23:56:26 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
pgadmin        | [2023-03-01 23:56:26 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I found different solutions online but I can't get it to work.

I am working with macOS Ventura and Docker Desktop for Mac.

Docker compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    container_name: postgis
    image: postgis/postgis:15-3.3
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=GOYN
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:6.20
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
      - PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE=True
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    volumes:
      - ./backend/pgadmin/servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
      - ./backend/pgadmin/pgpass:/var/lib/pgadmin/storage/pgadmin4_pgadmin.org/pgpass
    depends_on:
      - db
```

File ./backend/pgadmin/servers.json:

```
{
  "Servers": {
    "1": {
      "Name": "MYDB Server",
      "Group": "Servers",
      "Host": "db",
      "Port": 5432,
      "MaintenanceDB": "MYDB",
      "Username": "postgres",
      "PassFile": "/pgpass",
      "SSLMode": "prefer"
    }
  }
}
```

File ./backend/pgadmin/pgpass::

```
db:5432:MYDB:postgres:postgres
```

EDIT: based on @arsks answer, I created this Dockerfile:

```
FROM dpage/pgadmin4:6.20
ADD servers.json /pgadmin4/servers.json
ADD pgpass /var/lib/pgadmin/storage/pgadmin4_pgadmin.org/pgpass
RUN whoami
USER root
RUN chown -R pgadmin /var/lib/pgadmin
USER pgadmin
```

The server is automatically added to pgadmin. However, it seems that pgadmin cannot find the password:

```
pgadmin   | Error: connection to server at "db" (172.22.0.2), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `pgpass` volume mount:

```
    volumes:
      - ./backend/pgadmin/servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
      - ./backend/pgadmin/pgpass:/var/lib/pgadmin/storage/pgadmin4_pgadmin.org/pgpass
```

If you look at the image filesystem, you will see that `/var/lib/pgadmin` exists and is owned by user `pgadmin`:

```
$ docker run --rm --entrypoint sh dpage/pgadmin4:6.20  -c 'ls -ld /var/lib/pgadmin'
drwxrwxr-x    1 pgadmin  root             0 Feb  6 10:56 /var/lib/pgadmin
```

When you mount a file onto `/var/lib/pgadmin/storage/...`, Docker creates `/var/lib/pgadmin/storage` (and all subdirectories and files) as owned by `root`, effectively preventing the `pgadmin` user from writing any files in this directory.

---

One way of dealing with this issue is to create an "init container" that takes care of setting up a Docker volume with appropriate permissions, like this:

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  pg_data:
  pgadmin_data:

services:
  db:
    image: postgis/postgis:15-3.3
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=MYDB
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  init-pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:6.20
    user: root
    entrypoint:
      - sh
      - -c
      - |
        mkdir -p /var/lib/pgadmin/storage/pgadmin4_pgadmin.org/
        cp /config/pgpass /var/lib/pgadmin/storage/pgadmin4_pgadmin.org/pgpass
        chown -R pgadmin /var/lib/pgadmin
    volumes:
      - ./backend/pgadmin:/config
      - pgadmin_data:/var/lib/pgadmin

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:6.20
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
      - PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE=True
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin_data:/var/lib/pgadmin
      - ./backend/pgadmin/servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json

    depends_on:
      init-pgadmin:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
```

The `init-pgadmin` container runs before the `pgadmin` container. It copies the `pgpass` file into the correct location and sets the ownership appropriately.

---

For this example, the `pgpass` file looks like:

```
db:5432:MYDB:postgres:postgres
```

And the `servers.json` file looks like:

```
{
  "Servers": {
    "1": {
      "Name": "MYDB Server",
      "Group": "Servers",
      "Host": "db",
      "Port": 5432,
      "MaintenanceDB": "MYDB",
      "Username": "postgres",
      "PassFile": "/pgpass",
      "SSLMode": "prefer"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Based on your answer, I am trying to create a Dockerfile for pgadmin to keep my docker-compose file cleaner. However, pgadmin can't find the password yet. Could you me with that? I edited my question to include the dockerfile.

Comment: I tried you docker-compose as well and it seems to have the same password issue.

Comment: This runs without error as written. You can see a complete demo [here](https://asciinema.org/a/GW7gaiKyScGd34Jx4Ys8CFBQi). Note that in your example you're using the database name `GOYN` in in your `docker-compose.yaml` (in the `db` service) but `MYDB` in your `pgpass` file and `servers.json`. You need to make sure those match.